# How to sort Song Library in track number order

Tags: c#, sorting, windows-phone-8

I'd like to make some easy player for Windows Phone but I observed that SongLibrary is sorted by alphabetic (so stupid, I think). So my question is that how I can sort it by Track Number?

if I do next:

```
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
        songCollection = library.Songs;
```

the songCollection has all songs but in alphabetic order. So what next? I tried to understand "OrderBy method" but it made me just too confused.

Comment: What did you attempt to do with `OrderBy` that didn't work?  Did you look at the examples of its use in the documentation; did you look at examples of its use elsewhere on the web?  There are a few tens of thousand examples to choose from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) and [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. What you need is a delegate and the easiest way to get one is by using [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

```
List<Song> orderedSongs = songCollection.OrderBy(s => s.TrackNumber).ToList();
```

Additional [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call will cause the query execution and will materialize a list, so any time you refer to `orderedSongs` ordering will not be performed over and over again.

You could get the same using syntax based query:

```
List<Song> orderedSongs = (from s in songCollection
                           orderby s.TrackNumber
                           select s).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, This really solved it. The problem looks even too easy to solve. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 List<Song> orderedList =  songCollection.OrderBy(x => x.TrackNumber).ToList();
```

See this Sample:

```
        Pet[] pets = { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
                       new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
                       new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 } };

        IEnumerable<Pet> query = pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Age);
```